# Как устроена память процесса?

Tags: c++, ассемблер, указатели, память

Изучаю устройство памяти процесса. Как я понял, это можно изобразить так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал на C++ тестовую программу. Вот фрагмент кода:

```
char * p = new char[13];
cout << (int)p << endl;
*p = 0x66;
MessageBox(0, p, ar2, MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

В olly остановил выполнение программы на *p = 0x66:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В eax, равный 011E74A0, лежит адрес выделенной через new памяти. В olly в окне Memory map видно, что этот адрес идет уже после стека, а на первом изображении видно, что Heap должна быть после bbs и перед Stack. К тому же в olly во вкладке View неактивна кнопка Heap. Я так понимаю в данном случае куча даже не создалась? В ассемблере DS:[EAX](в olly ниже левее окна с ассемблерным кодом есть DS:[011E74A0]=0D), я перешел по адресу 011E74A0 и увидел, что там действительно лежит 0D. Абсолютный адрес, насколько я знаю, вычисляется как ЗначениеDS * 0x10 + 011E74A0. Получается DS = 0 или мне так повезло, что по адресу 011E74A0 лежит 0D? Помогите разобраться с устройством памяти в процессах.

Comment: Все эти картинки имеют, во-первых, дидактический характер (показать принципы), во-вторых, в разных ОС все это может быть совсем по-разному (у вас картинка для Linux, внизу тест для Windows), все это осложняется разными ухищрениями операционных систем... Все совсем не так, как на самом деле :) Могу порекомендовать, например, Столлингса, "Операционные системы", скоро выходит в "Диалектике" на русском, пока есть в сети на английском. Если вы не системный программист - эти вопросы вас не должны особо волновать, вообще говоря...

Comment: Я не планирую "погружаться" так глубоко во все тонкости организации памяти в разных ОС. Просто хотел написать прогу, которая будет искать в памяти процесса какое-то значение(планировал реализовать через winapi ReadProcessMemory). Перед этим хотел изучить организацию памяти в процессах, хотя бы на базовом уровне.

Comment: Тут просто картинка 1) не соответствует реальному разделению памяти из картинки 2) (совсем другая ОС)

Comment: Дело не совсем в картинке. Почему тогда в olly заблокирована кнопка View->Heap. По ощущениям char[13] располагается вовсе не в куче. К тому же возникает вопрос про DS(отредактирую свой вопрос).

Comment: @Александр "_ Абсолютный адрес, насколько я знаю, вычисляется как ЗначениеDS * 0x10 +..._". Вы знаете как он вычислялся в реальном режиме процессора, а во всех современных ОС используется защищенный режим, в котором совершенно другая адресация. В регистре DS у вас 0x2B что говорит что вы в 3 кольце защиты, а базовый адрес сегмента надо смотреть в 5 записи таблицы GDT.

Comment: @Александр Учитывая, что это GDT и запись всего лишь 5, значит в используемой ОС используется единое адресное пространство для всех процессов в системе. И куча находиться не в bss. Место под кучу new запрашивает у ОС и та дает ему блок из которого new уже выделяет кусочек под создаваемый объект. В exe файле вообще нет сегмента, который мог бы описать то, где находиться куча. А почему у вас кнопка в отладчике не работает, надо смотреть доку на отладчик. Скорее всего он просто не может определить где находиться куча.

Comment: Добавлю что ОС может выдать любой адрес для кучи, какой посчитает нужным, он не обязан находиться в каком то определенном месте относительно других сегментов программы.

Comment: Да, перепутал реальный и защищенный режимы. Спасибо, если отправите в ответе, то отмечу как решение.